# python setup.py test unable to fine tests when using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, setuptools, setup.py

My project directory looks like this

```
setup.py
chtools/
  __init__.py
  perspective-tool
  lib/
  tests/
    __init__.py
    setup.cfg
    test_perspective.py
```

when I run pytest from my project directory (i.e. same level as setup.py) everything works as expected.

```
(.venv) desktop:cloudhealth-tools$ pytest
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.6.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/jjk3/PycharmProjects/cloudhealth-tools, inifile:
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                           

chtools/tests/test_perspective.py ... [100%]
```

but when I run `python setup test` it is unable to find the tests.

```
(.venv) desktop:cloudhealth-tools$ python setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
writing chtools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to chtools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to chtools.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to chtools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to chtools.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'chtools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'chtools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I added `setup_requires` and `tests_require` as stated in the pytest docs, https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.9.1/goodpractices.html, but no luck.

`setup.py` is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('README.md') as readme_file:
    readme = readme_file.read()

setup(name='chtools',
      version='1.0.6',
      description='Automation Tools for CloudHealth',
      url='https://github.com/bluechiptek/cloudhealth-tools',
      author='BlueChipTek',
      author_email='joe@bluechiptek.com',
      long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
      long_description=readme,
      license='GPLv3',
      packages=find_packages(),
      python_requires='>=3',
      install_requires=[
            'certifi==2018.1.18',
            'chardet==3.0.4',
            'idna==2.6',
            'PyYAML==3.13',
            'requests==2.18.4',
            'urllib3==1.22'
      ],
      setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
      tests_require=['pytest'],
      entry_points={
            'console_scripts': ['perspective-tool=chtools.perspective_tool:main']
      },
      classifiers=[
            'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)',
            'Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only'
      ]
      )
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You don't seem to have actually configured a test suite in your `setup.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setup.cfg` resides in a wrong directory: it must be adjacent to `setup.py`:

```
chtools/
  __init__.py
  lib/
  perspective-tool
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_perspective.py
setup.cfg
setup.py
```

You should declare an alias `test` in `setup.cfg`:

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner